# useForm hidden nested file input not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have a form with a custom file input.  I am using react-hook-form.  In the past I have been able to hide the default `<input type="file"/>` and add my own custom button, targeting the input with `ref.current.click` and triggering the `onChange` event from there.

However, while experimenting with react-hook-form it does not seem as straight forward.  I am under the impression that I have to use `Controller` component from `useForm` but I can't seem to get it to work.

Currently, when I click my Add Image button, it does not prompt me to choose a file.

```
const ImageInput = () => {
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState();

  const pickImageHandler = async () => {
    //I dont know what to ref here??
    ref.current.click();
  };

  const imageChange = (e) => {
    console.log("imageChange onChange triggered");
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files.length > 0) {
      setSelectedImage(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  <>
    <Controller
      control={control}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <input
          control={control}
          type="file"
          accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg"
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          onChange={imageChange}
          {...field}
        />
      )}
    />
    <Button
      type="button"
      variant="contained"
      className={classes.pickImageButton}
      onClick={pickImageHandler}
    >
      Add Image
    </Button>
  </>;
}; 

 const PostForm = (props) => {
    const submitFunction= async (data) => {
      //handle submitForm with formData
    }
    <form onSubmit={submitFunction}>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <ImageInput {...register("cardImage")} name="cardImage" />
      </FormProvider>
      <Button type="submit" className={classes.postButton}>
        Post
      </Button>
    <form/>;
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having multiple errors in your code, I've fixed it all and the code below. Because [`register()`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register) returns a set a props including the input `ref` callback, you need to create a wrapper ref callback to initialize both RHF ref and your own ref too:

```
const { ref, ...fields } = register('cardImage');
const inputRef = React.useRef(); // your ref to call click() imperatively
```

```
const ImageInput = () => {
  const { register } = useFormContext();
  const { ref, ...fields } = register('cardImage');
  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  const pickImageHandler = () => {
    inputRef.current?.click();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="file"
        accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg"
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
        {...fields}
        ref={(instance) => {
          ref(instance); // RHF wants a reference to this input
          inputRef.current = instance; // We also need it to manipulate the elemnent
        }}
      />
      <Button type="button" variant="contained" onClick={pickImageHandler}>
        Add Image
      </Button>
    </>
  );
};
```

If you want to submit only one image you can process after the user submitted:

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
  if (data.cardImage && data.cardImage.length > 0) {
    data.cardImage = data.cardImage[0];
  }

  console.log(data);
  // submit the data
};
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am now trying to add an image preview to the image selected and I'm running into a similar problem.  I wasn't sure if I should have just asked hear but I ended up asking a new question and in case you wanted to lend your expertise it can be found below.  Thanks again.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69889823/react-hook-form-nested-file-input-preview-image-onchange-event-handling

Answer (score 0):

I have found this issue myself. I found a good solution was to just set the height property of the image input to zero:

```
<input id='image' type='file' accept='image/*' style={{height: 0}}></input>
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33594475)